# Univocity - AutomaticConfiguration do not work with MultiBeanListProcessor

Tags: java, univocity

When I instantiate a `FixedWidthParser` with a `MultiBeanListProcessor` the `CommonParserSettings#configureFromAnnotations(beanClass)` is not called because, it is not an instance of AbstractBeanProcessor. Should not the method be called for each `AbstractProcessorBean` in the `MultiBeanListProcessor`?

The example code:

```
FixedWidthParserSettings settings = new FixedWidthParserSettings();
settings.setAutoConfigurationEnabled(true);
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(false);
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");

MultiBeanListProcessor processor = new MultiBeanListProcessor(FileHeader.class, ...);   // FileHeader has an @Headers and fields with @Parsed
settings.setProcessor(processor);

FixedWidthParser parser = new FixedWidthParser(settings);     // Here it should call configureFromAnnotations

try (Reader reader = getReader("/positional-file")) {

    parser.parse(reader);   // the exception is throwed here

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is an abbreviated version of the bean:

```
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.FixedWidth;
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Headers;
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Parsed;
import com.univocity.parsers.fixed.FieldAlignment;

@Headers(sequence = { "bankCode", "batchCode", "registerType" }, extract = false, write = false)
public class FileHeader {

    @Parsed
    @FixedWidth(value = 3, alignment = FieldAlignment.RIGHT, padding = '0')
    private Integer bankCode;

    @Parsed
    @FixedWidth(value = 4, alignment = FieldAlignment.RIGHT, padding = '0')
    private Integer batchCode;

    @Parsed
    @FixedWidth(value = 1, alignment = FieldAlignment.RIGHT, padding = '0')
    private Integer registerType;`

     /** getters and setters  */
}
```

The exception:

```
com.univocity.parsers.common.DataProcessingException: Could not find fields [bankCode, bankName, batchCode] in input. Please enable header extraction in the parser settings in order to match field names.
Internal state when error was thrown: line=0, column=0, record=1, charIndex=240
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.core.BeanConversionProcessor.mapFieldIndexes(BeanConversionProcessor.java:360)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.core.BeanConversionProcessor.mapValuesToFields(BeanConversionProcessor.java:289)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.core.BeanConversionProcessor.createBean(BeanConversionProcessor.java:457)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.core.AbstractBeanProcessor.rowProcessed(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:51)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.core.AbstractMultiBeanProcessor.rowProcessed(AbstractMultiBeanProcessor.java:101)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.Internal.process(Internal.java:21)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.rowProcessed(AbstractParser.java:596)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:132)
```

The value of `context.headers()` at `BeanConversionProcessor.mapFieldIndexes` is null.

Is there any other way to use `MultiBeanListProcessor` with `AutoConfiguration` from `@Headers`?

P.S.: Its work if I change the `MultiBeanListProcessor(FileHeader.class)` for a `BeanListProcessor(FileHeader.class)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fixed in version 2.4.2. A SNAPSHOT build has this fixed already and is currently available via maven or directly from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.4.2-SNAPSHOT/).

Hope this helps